# Does localization of a Noetherian ring always give a local ring?

Tags: abstract-algebra, ring-theory

I have a local ring $A$ and suppose I localized this ring at prime $P$. 
Is the localized ring $A_P$ a local ring? I was wondering if it requires additional properties on $A$. Thank you very much!

Comment: Is every localized ring $S^{-1}A$ a local ring?

Comment: Localizing at a prime produces a local ring, the multiplicative set being the complement of the prime ideal.  It is possible to "localize" or construct a ring of quotients (or fractions, as some prefer) using any multiplicative set.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well, yes, if you mean a local *noetherian* ring: the localisation of any (commutative) ring at a prime ideal $\mathfrak p$ is a local ring, with maximal ideal $\mathfrak pA_{\mathfrak p}$, and any ring of fractions of a noetherian ring is noetherian.

Comment: Could the localization of *any* commutative ring at a prime be non-local? (Local does not necessarily include noetherian.)

Comment: Apparently this is not so clear to the O.P. Anyway it is not because the procedure is  *called* localisation that the result is a local ring. It's a result.